# Lipschitz functions carry $F_\sigma$ to $F_\sigma$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Lipschitz function.  I want to show that it carries $F_\sigma$ sets to $F_\sigma$ sets.

I'm not sure how to demonstrate this.  Specifically I'm not sure what property of continuity or Lipschitz would preserve the $F_\sigma$ property.  I do know that this is true: $f(\bigcup_{i} A_i)=\bigcup_{i}f(A_i)$.

Comment: What is an $F_{\sigma}$ set?

Comment: A countable union of closed sets.

Comment: Thank you! And for editing as well!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Hint*: A closed set $K \subseteq [a,b]$ is compact (as $[a,b]$ is). Hence its image $f[K]$ under the continuous function $f$ is compact also.

Comment: Does it just immediately follow that $f(\bigcup_{i} K_i)=\bigcup_{i}f(K_i)$ since subsets of compact sets are compact?

Comment: You said you know about this. It holds $x \in f[\bigcup_i K_i] \iff \exists y \in \bigcup_i K_i. f(y) = x $ $\iff  \exists i\exists y \in K_i. f(y) = x \iff \exists i. x \in f[K_i] \iff x\in \bigcup_i f[K_i]$.

Comment: I think it was just stated as a definition in Principles of Analysis by Rudin.  I didn't know (or most likely cannot recall) that it works for compactness.

Comment: The statement $f[\bigcup_i K_i] = \bigcup_i f[K_i]$ has nothing to do with the compactness of the $K_i$. It just follows from the definition of union and image.

Comment: I'm sorry...I don't follow.  Compact sets are closed and bounded and preserved by a continuous function f.  However, $F_\sigma$ just have the property of being a countable union of closed sets.

Comment: Let $A$ be an $F_\sigma$-set. Then $A$ can be written as $A = \bigcup_{i\ge 1} K_i$ with compact(!) $K_i$. Now the $f[K_i]$ are compact, hence closed, so $f[A] = f[\bigcup_i K_i] = \bigcup_i f[K_i]$ is a .....

Comment: Why is a closed set the countable union of compact sets?

Comment: $A$ is an $F_\sigma$-set in $[a,b]$. Hence it's the union of countable many **closed** $K_i \subseteq [a,b]$. As $[a,b]$ is compact, each of it's closed subsets is also. So $A$ is a countable union of **compact** sets.